# Is it possible to get a clean url to be used in Views comment counts?

Tags: 7, views, comments, tokens, uri

I have a Views view of some news nodes.
Each of the news nodes has "Generate automatic URL alias" ticked in the "URL path settings" of the node. This is great and gives me nice clean URL's.

However in my comments field in the view when I go to "REWRITE RESULTS" "Output this field as a link" and set the "Link Path" I am unable to find a token that gives me the same clean url that my title field can have or even my Node: Link field.

Is it possible to use the clean urls for comments and if so what is the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be done through rewriting, it's quite limited and never has given me what I want. At any rate you could be better off if you used the row-theming technique, which is in turn powerful. Then you could build your own links the way you want, wrapping the URLs in [drupal_get_path_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) to get nice-looking addresses.

Comment: If I wrap a clean url in drupal_get_path_alias will the url remain unchanged? I ask as I get clean urls and no clean urls depending on context but have one template for both situations.